# Any way to handle "predictable branches" faster?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, conditional-statements, x86-64

I have some code in which there are two or three branches which you don't know what way they will go, but after the first time they are hit, it is either 100% certain, or close to that, that the same path will happen again. I have noticed that use of the __builtin_likely doesn't do much in terms of avoiding branch misses. And even though branch prediction does a good job when my function is called repeatedly in a short time span..as soon as there is other stuff going on between calls to my function, performance degrades substantially. What are some ways around this or some techniques I can look into? Any way to somehow "tag" these branches for when they are reached again after some vagrancy?

Comment: This is generally what [PGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) is for, if your compiler supports it.

Comment: Performance always degrades when "there's other stuff going on".  Use a good profiler so you are not guessing at this.

Comment: I have seen in the past the same function implemented twice, with the builtin hints reversed and having a dispatcher pointer that would be reset on the mispredicted branch... I am not sure I would do that outside of a very tight loop, and you should do as Hans Passant says: **profile** and determine whether branch misprediction is really the issue (if there are other things executing in between, the cost of the misprediction might not really be an important chunk of the pie)

Comment: @David Rodriguez, dont you need another branch to check whether you mispredicted the branch and need to toggle the pointer?

Comment: @Passant, yes I am using cachegrind right now..i think caching might also play a role in this. mispredicted loops shouldnt cost more than double digit cycles so perhaps it is caching that is a bigger issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use templates to generate a different version of the function for each code path, then use a function pointer to select one at runtime when you find out which way the condition goes.

Answer (score 0):

The branch predictor and compiler intrinsics are all you've got. At best, you can look at the assembly and try to hand-roll some optimization yourself, but you won't find much.

Comment: don't you mean __builtin_expect ?